# How to export/save DataSnapshot Firebase in Json file?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have very big problem. I have this structure in my Firebase:

[image: my Firebase structure]

I would like to save this structure in JSON file/String no matter. I would get such a result:

```
{
"-Ka8_NYNxaFCcZQ3eaTp" : {
  "Persons" : {
    "-KaHUTUan-l06OVjsUlu" : {
      "birthDay" : "13.01.2017",
      "deathDay" : "06.01.2017",
      "lastName" : "LastName1",
      "latitude" : "54.2039383",
      "longitude" : "16.1930868",
      "name" : "name1"
    },
    "-KaHU_nPOE2NlqTbhLxT" : {
      "birthDay" : "11.01.2017",
      "deathDay" : "03.01.2017",
      "lastName" : "LastName2",
      "latitude" : "54.2039383",
      "longitude" : "16.1930868",
      "name" : "name2"
    }

  },
  "city" : "Wroclaw",
  "county" : "county1",
  "nameCemetery" : "nameCemetery1",
  "province" : "province1",
  "street" : "street1"
}
```

I tried through DataSnaphot but the result was not in the format JSON, e.g:

```
{-Ka8_NYNxaFCcZQ3eaTp={nameCemetery=nameCemetery1, street=street1, county=county1, province=province1, Persons={-KaHU_nPOE2NlqTbhLxT={name=Damian, latitude=54.2039383, lastName=Szeeczyk, birthDay=11.01.2017, longitude=16.1930868, deathDay=03.01.2017}, -KaHUTUan-l06OVjsUlu={name=name1, latitude=54.2039383, lastName=LastName1, birthDay=13.01.2017, longitude=16.1930868, deathDay=06.01.2017}}, city=Wroclaw}}
```

The most important for me is not to create JSONArray Persons, because then my application will run incorrectly.
In short, I would like to make a copy node (in my example key -"Ka8_NYNxaFCcZQ3eaTp"

Comment: I think best practice is to make `Person` custom object. Have you tried it?

Comment: Already I solved my problem. Simple. I copy data from URL firebase ;)